# Create a Hardware diagnosis canonical answer

Tags: discussion, canonical-answer

I think that there are many posts that begin with something like "My computer does not start up", Fuzzy scree on boot, etc, and that it would be a useful thing to have.

I was thinking that it should be organized something like this.

#### Part 1:

- BIOS settings
- Generic type problems with diagnosis (bad screen for example)

#### Part 2:

- Bad RAM causes...
- Bad Video card causes...
- Bad hard drive causes...
  ect

All of this should be kept as generic as possible of course, but most computers are built in mostly the same way (for the most part they all have hard drives, usb drives, BIOS, power supplies, etc) and so much of the information should be the same (at least on the diagnosis side, if not the solutions).

Thoughts on creating such a thing?

**Update:** Here it is, feel free to comment/update [How to Diagnose a Pre-Operating System Load or Hardware Issue](https://superuser.com/q/437005/82812)

Comment: If we don't have this already, I'd say, just go ahead. If you have a couple of ideas already, maybe write up an answer *before* you post the question and post them together. Make it community wiki and explicitly encourage others to add details.

Comment: @slhck will do in a few hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's already sort of some information on this within our [community-faq](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq)s:

### [How do I troubleshoot when I have no clue where to start?](https://superuser.com/questions/260043/how-do-i-troubleshoot-when-i-have-no-clue-where-to-start)

### [How do I troubleshoot hardware issues related to a computer freeze/crash?](https://superuser.com/questions/224515/how-do-i-troubleshoot-hardware-issues-related-to-a-computer-freeze-crash)

### [How to Diagnose a Pre-Operating System Load or Hardware Issue](https://superuser.com/questions/437005/how-to-diagnose-a-pre-operating-system-load-or-hardware-issue)

Feel free to either update this with more detailed information, or if the stuff you're thinking of writing would be better suited to a new post, make sure to reference those.

Comment: Will do, thanks.